# Quicksort implementation not sorting in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, quicksort, partitioning

It's been 2 days I'm trying to write a quicksort implementation in C but it does not work. I mean, it does compile but the output is not what I expected.

I have been studying a Data Struct book, it's translated to portuguese tho, my native language, anyway... I'll past the instructions here below along with my code.

[QuickSort Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb2NU.png)
[Partition Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdMdl.png)

```
//
//  Quick sort V2.c
//  IFTM Exercises
//
//  Created by Lelre Ferreira on 7/9/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Lelre Ferreira. All rights reserved.
//

#define size 5
#include <stdio.h>

void printfArrays(int *array);
void receiveArray(int *array);
int QuickSortPartition(int *array, int begin, int end);
void QuickSortFunction(int *array, int begin, int end);


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){

    int array[size];

    receiveArray(array);
    printfArrays(array);

    return 0;
}

void receiveArray(int* array){

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Insert value of [%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
}

void printfArrays(int *array){

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Value sorted: %d\n", array[i]);
    }
}

int QuickSortPartition(int *array, int begin, int end){


    int pivot = array[end];
    int i = (begin - 1), j = 0;

    for (j = begin; j <= end - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            array[i] = array[j];
        }
    }
    array[i + 1] = array[end];
    return (i + 1);
}

void QuickSortFunction(int *array, int begin, int end){

    if (begin < end) {
        int pivot = QuickSortPartition(array, begin, end);
        QuickSortPartition(array, begin, pivot - 1);
        QuickSortPartition(array, pivot + 1, end);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `main` is never calling any sorting function.

Comment: It's good idea to learn using a debugger. This way you can see what functions are called, what the intermediate state is and pinpoint errors much easier.

Comment: @Lelre Ferreira It is evident that the function QuickSortPartition is incorrect.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){`  This will cause the compiler to output two warning messages about unused parameters. ( `argc` and `argv` )  Suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`  -- `int  main( void )`

Comment: It appears that `QuickSortFunction` is intended to recurse, which would be common, *but it doesn't*.  Where it ought to be calling itself (twice), it is instead calling `QuickSortPartition`.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {`  it is best to limit the scope of a variable.  Suggest: `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%d", &array[i]);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  The `scanf()` family of functions return the number of successful 'input format conversions'.  Suggest: `if( scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for array entry failed\n" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}`  Where `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed in the `stdlib.h` header file

Comment: The quicksort()` function is 'normally' accompanied by a function that actually compares a pair of entries and returns an indication: -1 or 0 or +1 to indicate which is larger, smaller, equal

Comment: regarding: `for (j = begin; j <= end - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            array[i] = array[j];
        }
    }
    array[i + 1] = array[end];`  this fails to swap the two 'target' entries in the array.  Suggest something like: `int temp = array[end];  array[end] = array[i];  array[i] = temp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things wrong:

1. You never call your sorting function.
2. Once you fix (1), you'll find your partition function is completely broken. You're trying to use the [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) and it doesn't match anywhere close to what it should be.

Whatever translation you performed for that algorithm for (2), it's wrong. The general algorithm for a Lomuto partition with a fixed pivot selection always at the end (a terrible choice, but that's beyond the scope of this question) is as follows:

**Updated Partition Function**

```
// added to make the partition algorithm easier to understand.
void swap_int(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a  = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int QuickSortPartition(int *array, int begin, int end){

    int i=begin, j;

    for (j = begin; j <= end; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] < array[end])
            swap_int(array+j, array + i++);
    }
    swap_int(array+i, array+end);

    return i;
}
```

Here `i` denotes the active slot where the pivot value will eventually reside. Initially the pivot is stored at `array[end]`. Once the for-loop sweep is done, `i` is sitting on the slot where the final swap will put the pivot into place. It is also the return value of the function, used by the caller to denote what *not* to include in later recursions (because its value is already home).

The final result looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printfArrays(int *array);
void receiveArray(int *array);
int QuickSortPartition(int *array, int begin, int end);
void QuickSortFunction(int *array, int begin, int end);

#define size 5

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){

    int array[size];

    receiveArray(array);
    QuickSortFunction(array, 0, size-1);
    printfArrays(array);

    return 0;
}

void receiveArray(int* array){

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Insert value of [%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", array+i);
    }
}

void printfArrays(int *array){

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Value sorted: %d\n", array[i]);
    }
}

static void swap_int(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a  = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int QuickSortPartition(int *array, int begin, int end){

    int i=begin, j;

    for (j = begin; j <= end; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] < array[end])
            swap_int(array+j, array + i++);
    }
    swap_int(array+i, array+end);

    return i;
}

void QuickSortFunction(int *array, int begin, int end){

    if (begin < end) {
        int pivot = QuickSortPartition(array, begin, end);
        QuickSortFunction(array, begin, pivot - 1);
        QuickSortFunction(array, pivot + 1, end);
    }
}
```

**Input**

```
 4 1 3 5 2
```

**Output**

```
Value sorted: 1
Value sorted: 2
Value sorted: 3
Value sorted: 4
Value sorted: 5
```

There are a *multitude* of other unrelated things in this code that would be wise to address (checking IO, a better pivot selection scheme such as median-of-three, etc.), but the basic problems are addressed above.

Comment: Thank for your help, I've done some mistakes, I was sort of tired of writing the code over and over again. I made the corrections are it's working as it should now.

Comment: @LelreFerreira This is actually even easier in C, which allows rebasing the array pointer argument to the recursive calls. It means you can do this with only two arguments (a pointer to/in the array, and a length argument. If you're interested in seeing what that looks like I can update this answer with an addendum, but a little searching of quicksort questions/answers in C on this site will just-as-well lead you to what I'm describing. Regardless, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote a function then test it before using it in a program.

The function `QuickSortPartition` is evidently wrong.

Consider the following demonstrative program with your function implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int QuickSortPartition(int *array, int begin, int end){


    int pivot = array[end];
    int i = (begin - 1), j = 0;

    for (j = begin; j <= end - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            array[i] = array[j];
        }
    }
    array[i + 1] = array[end];
    return (i + 1);
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 5, 4, 2, 1, 3 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    QuickSortPartition( a, 0, ( int )( N - 1 ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Its output is

```
5 4 2 1 3 
2 1 3 1 3
```

You need to swap values in the function instead of using a simple assignment. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t QuickSortPartition( int *array, size_t begin, size_t end )
{
    const int pivot = array[end];

    size_t i = begin - 1;

    for ( size_t j = begin; j < end; j++ ) 
    {
        if ( array[j] <= pivot ) 
        {
            int tmp = array[++i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    int tmp = array[++i];
    array[i] = array[end];
    array[end] = tmp;

    return i;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 5, 4, 2, 1, 3 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t partition = QuickSortPartition( a, 0, N - 1 );

    printf( "%zu: ", partition );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Its output is

```
5 4 2 1 3 
2: 2 1 3 4 5
```

For indices I used the type `size_t` (and you should do the same) instead of the type `int`.

And within the function `QuickSortFunction` you need call it itself instead of the function `QuickSortPartition`.

```
void QuickSortFunction(int *array, size_t begin, size_t end){

    if (begin < end) {
        size_t pivot = QuickSortPartition(array, begin, end);
        QuickSortFunction(array, begin, pivot - 1);
        QuickSortFunction(array, pivot + 1, end);
    }

}
```

Take into account that this initialization in the declaration of the function `QuickSortPartition`

```
int i = (begin - 1), j = 0;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is bad.  (It seems everyone copies the algorithm from a bad example:)). And the function is inefficient when all elements is less or equal to the value of pivot.

Also you could write a separate function that swaps two elements of an array.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how the code of the function `QuickSortPartition` can be made better.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap( int *a, int *b )
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

size_t QuickSortPartition( int *array, size_t begin, size_t end )
{
    const int pivot = array[end];

    size_t i = begin;

    for ( size_t j = begin; j < end; j++ ) 
    {
        if ( array[j] <= pivot ) 
        {
            if ( i != j ) swap( &array[i], &array[j] );
            ++i;
        }
    }

    if ( i != end ) swap( &array[i], &array[end] );

    return i;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 5, 4, 2, 1, 3 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t partition = QuickSortPartition( a, 0, N - 1 );

    printf( "%zu: ", partition );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I fixed the issues in the previous code and I ended up making another one using while, I will leave both here.

```
//
//  Quick sort V2 fixed.c
//  IFTM Exercises
//
//  Created by Lelre Ferreira on 7/11/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Lelre Ferreira. All rights reserved.
//

#define size 5
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int *array);
void receiveArray(int *array);

void QuickSwap(int* a, int* b);
void QuickSort(int *array, int begin, int end);
int  QuickSortPartition(int *array, int begin, int end);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){

    int array[size];

    receiveArray(array);
    QuickSort(array, 0, size-1);
    printArray(array);

    return 0;
}

void printArray(int *array){

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Value sorted: %d\n", array[i]);
    }
}

void receiveArray(int *array){

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Insert value of [%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
}

void QuickSwap(int* a, int* b){

    int x = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = x;
}

void QuickSort(int *array, int begin, int end){

    if (begin < end) {
        int pivot = QuickSortPartition(array, begin, end);
        QuickSort(array, begin, pivot - 1);
        QuickSort(array, pivot + 1, end);
    }
}

int QuickSortPartition(int *array, int begin, int end){

    int pivot = array[end];
    int i = begin - 1, j = 0;

    for (j = begin; j <= end - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            QuickSwap(&array[i], &array[j]);
        }
    }
    QuickSwap(&array[i + 1], &array[j]);
    return (i + 1);
}
```

Second version:

```
//
//  Quick sort V1.c
//  IFTM Exercises
//
//  Created by Lelre Ferreira on 7/8/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Lelre Ferreira. All rights reserved.
//

#define size 5
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int *array);
void QuickSortFunction(int *array, int begin, int end);
int QuickSortPartition(int *array, int begin, int end);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){

    int array[] = {2, 3, 1, 5, 4};

        QuickSortFunction (array, 0, size-1);
        printArray(array);

    return 0;
}

void printArray(int* array){

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Value sorted: %d\n", array[i]);
    }
}

int QuickSortPartition(int *array, int begin, int end){

    int left, right;
    int pivot, aux;

    right = end;
    left = begin;
    pivot = array[begin];

    while (left < right) {
        while (array[left] <= pivot)
            left++;
        while (array[right] > pivot)
                right--;
                if (left < right) {
                    aux = array[left];
                    array[left] = array[right];
                    array[right] = aux;
                }
            }

            array[begin] = array[right];
            array[right] = pivot;
            return right;
}

void QuickSortFunction(int *array, int begin, int end){

    if (begin < end) {
        int pivot = QuickSortPartition(array, begin, end);
        QuickSortFunction(array, begin, pivot - 1);
        QuickSortFunction(array, pivot + 1, end);
    }
}
```