# Problem with quicksort function on arrays of 64 bits integers in C

Tags: c, 64-bit, quicksort

I am currently working in C with large sets of 64-bit integers, and I naturally need a quicksort algorithm to simplify any incoming function on those sets. I tried a classic implementation already found in several places on this website (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973517/quicksort-implementation-not-sorting-in-c)) and ended up with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>         
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static void swap_int(uint64_t *a, uint64_t *b)
{
    uint64_t tmp = *a;
    *a  = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

uint64_t QuickSortPartition(uint64_t *array, uint64_t begin, uint64_t end) {

    uint64_t i = begin, j;

    for (j = begin; j <= end; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] < array[end])
            swap_int(array + j, array + i++);
    }
    swap_int(array + i, array + end);

    return i;
}

void QuickSortFunction(uint64_t *array, uint64_t begin, uint64_t end) {
    if (begin < end) {
        uint64_t pivot = QuickSortPartition(array, begin, end);
        QuickSortFunction(array, begin, pivot - 1);
        QuickSortFunction(array, pivot + 1, end);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine for small sets as far as I have tested. I then went on to pseudorandomly generate 64 bits integers using the following function, and test the quicksort:

```
uint64_t rnd64(uint64_t n)
{
    const uint64_t z = 0x9FB21C651E98DF25;

    n ^= ((n << 49) | (n >> 15)) ^ ((n << 24) | (n >> 40));
    n *= z;
    n ^= n >> 35;
    n *= z;
    n ^= n >> 28;

    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int n = 64;
    uint64_t Size = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    uint64_t *S = malloc(Size * sizeof(uint64_t));

    uint64_t state = 1;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        const uint64_t n = rnd64(state++);
        S[i] = n;
    }

    QuickSortFunction(S, 0, Size - 1);

    printf("Sorted S:\n");
    Display_set(S, Size, n);
}
```

Where `Size` is arbitrarily entered as an `argv` parameter. Moreover, `Display_set` is a standard function printing each element of `S` in binary and in order.
This works perfectly fine for `Size <= 11`, but once `Size = 11`, this produces a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong here?

I tried implementing other standard quicksort methods such as the pivot in first or last position, to no avail. As this function should (unless I am also wrong here) work for int type, I am guessing the transition to `uint64_t` induces an error.

Comment: **Display_set is a standard function**. The C standard doesn't specify this function. Post a [mcve].

Comment: Consider what happens when `pivot == 0`.

Comment: You appear to have made no attempts to debug. If you had, you have noticed that `end` becomes `18446744073709551615` (or some other silly value).

Comment: Why are you not using the standard `qsort()` function for this?

Comment: You code only has one line in error that is causing the problem, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel; check out the C standard library function [qsort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html). It lets you specify the size of the elements, which you can set to `sizeof(your integer type)`.

If quicksort isn't the algorithm you want, its sister functions mergesort and heapsort may be more useful.

The comparison function -- the last argument -- can be simply implemented as

```c
int compare_int_type(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(const int_type *)a - *(const int_type *)b;
}
```

qsort is then called as

```c
// for the last argument, you're passing the function,
// so it's important not to write compare().
qsort(array, size, sizeof(*array), compare);
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't even know that was a thing. Thank you so much for saving me a headache.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help. The compare_int_type function could possibly be written to take arguments of type `const int_type *` (thereby removing the ugly cast), but I don't know function pointers that well, and that could theoretically result in a type mismatch when trying to pass the function to `qsort`.

Comment: That comparison function is unsafe because the subtraction can overflow.  And if `int_type` is not `int` or something narrower, then it is unsafe also because conversion of the difference to type `int` can overflow.

Comment: `return *(const int_type *)a - *(const int_type *)b` is a poor choice.  The return value is truncated (and possible the wrong sign) when `int_type` is wider than `int` and risks signed integer overflow when `int_type` is `int1`.

Comment: Better as `int_type ia = *(const int_type *)a;  int_type ib = *(const int_type *)b; return (a > b) - (a < b);` which always works.

Answer (score 1):

On review, OP says, `Size` was 11 or so and therefore the overflow issue below is not a concern for OP now.

---

**Potential overflow**

The type of the numbers is `uint64_t` --> good.

The array size and indexing should be `size_t`.  If `Size` is a  value more than `SIZE_MAX/sizeof(uint64_t)`, then `Size*sizeof(uint64_t)` is too big for `malloc(size_t)` and you have problems.

Limit array.

Comment: If doing a 64 bit build, then `size_t` is 64 bits (essentially size_t == uint64_t), and overflow isn't an issue.

Comment: @rcgldr 64-bit usual refers to the native processor integer width.  `size_t` depends more on  memory space.  C does not require a compiler with a _64 bit build_ to use 64-bit `size_t`.  IAC, OP  did not express that the machine was using a a 64 bit build.  Lots of possibilities.  This answer points out that better code would use `size_t` for array sizing and indexing.

Comment: If `size_t` is not 64 bits on a 64 bit build, `uint64_t` would make more sense, although in this case, for quicksort compare of indexes, `int64_t` makes more sense, so that -1 < 0 (instead of 0xffffffffffffffff > 0). On a 32 bit system, generally there is a max of 3GB of virtual address space (the 1GB used by OS), so if an array fits in the virtual address space, again overflow is not an issue, if using unsigned 32 bit integers, but then requires code to handle the 0, -1 (0, 0xffffffff) case.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question just needs one line fixed, to change begin and end from `uint64_t` to `int64_t`.  This is done to handle cases l like begin = 0 and end = 0xffffffffffffffff, which should be begin = 0 and end = -1 so that `if (begin < end) {` is false in those cases.

```
void QuickSortFunction(uint64_t *array, int64_t begin, int64_t end){
```

QuickSortPartition() is doing one more loop than needed, but it's not a problem.

```
    for (j = begin; j < end; j++)       /* no need for j <= end */
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle problem in your implementation: if `QuickSortPartition` returns `0`, which happens when the pivot element is greater or equal to all entries at the beginning of the array, passing `pivot - 1` in a recursive call passes a very large (`UINT64_MAX`) value as the `end` index, causing `QuickSortPartition` to iterate far beyond the end of the array, invoking undefined behavior such as a segmentation fault as you observe.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>         
#include <time.h>

static void swap_uint64(uint64_t *a, uint64_t *b) {
    uint64_t tmp = *a;
    *a  = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

size_t QuickSortPartition(uint64_t *array, size_t begin, size_t end) {
    size_t i = begin;
    for (size_t j = begin; j < end; j++) {
        if (array[j] < array[end])
            swap_uint64(array + j, array + i++);
    }
    swap_uint64(array + i, array + end);
    return i;
}

void QuickSortFunction(uint64_t *array, size_t begin, size_t end) {
    if (begin < end) {
        size_t pivot = QuickSortPartition(array, begin, end);
        if (pivot > begin)
            QuickSortFunction(array, begin, pivot - 1);
        QuickSortFunction(array, pivot + 1, end);
    }
}
```

Note however that this simplistic implementation has a pathological case if the array is already sorted: the complexity is quadratic and the recursion depth can reach the length of the array, causing a stack overflow.

The recursion problem can be handled with this modified version that only recurses on the smaller slice:

```
void QuickSortFunction(uint64_t *array, size_t begin, size_t end) {
    while (begin < end) {
        size_t pivot = QuickSortPartition(array, begin, end);
        if (pivot - begin < end - pivot) {
            if (pivot > begin)
                QuickSortFunction(array, begin, pivot - 1);
            begin = pivot + 1;
        } else {
            QuickSortFunction(array, pivot + 1, end);
            end = pivot - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This does not solve the pathologic cases where substantial portions of the array are already sorted. To sort the array more reliably, with a method that may not always be a variation of QuickSort, you should use the standard library function `qsort`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_uint64(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const uint64_t *a = aa;
    const uint64_t *b = bb;
    return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}

void QuickSortFunction(uint64_t *array, size_t begin, size_t end) {
    if (begin < end)
        qsort(array, end - begin + 1, sizeof(*array), compare_uint64);
}
```

For very large sets, you could get better performance by implementing Radix Sort, which is well suited for arrays of unsigned integers.